# Android Camera photo cannot confirm creation

Tags: android

I want to open the camera, save the photo and pass it to an `ImageView`. However, I am able to take the photo but I cannot confirm the photo creation. I can also cancel or retake the photo but not confirm.

This is the related code that I used. It doesn't even get to `onActivityResult` when pressing the confirm button.

```
    camera_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(), Manifest.permission.CAMERA) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED){
                requestPermissions(new String[]{ Manifest.permission.CAMERA }, CAMERA_CODE);
            }else{
                OpenCamera();
            }
        }
    });

private void OpenCamera(){
    File file = new File(DbHelper.ImageFolder.getPath() + File.separator + NewImageFileName());
    Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    Uri uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this, getApplicationContext().getPackageName() + ".provider", file);
    image_path = uri.getPath();
    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, uri);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
    startActivityForResult(intent, CAMERA_CODE);
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    if (grantResults.length == 0 || grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED)
        return;
    switch (requestCode){
        case CAMERA_CODE:
            OpenCamera();
            break;
        case GALLERY_CODE:
            OpenGallery();
            break;
    }
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (resultCode != RESULT_OK) return;
    Bitmap image = null;
    switch (requestCode){
        case CAMERA_CODE:
            image = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(image_path);
            break;
        case GALLERY_CODE:
            try {
                image = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), data.getData());
                image_path = NewImageFileName();
                // Then saves to local
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            break;
        default:
            return;
    }
    food_image.setImageBitmap(image);
}
```

[image]

My cell phone is OnePlus 7 Pro. My code works on another phone I borrowed. I wonder if my code is wrong (or it needs some code to handle compatibility) or there is something wrong with the device. On the emulator (Pixel 3 XL), it keeps taking photos and there is no confirm.

My project is [here](https://github.com/SeakyLuo/RandomMenu/tree/master/app/src/main).

Code posted is [here](https://github.com/SeakyLuo/RandomMenu/blob/master/app/src/main/java/personalprojects/seakyluo/randommenu/EditFoodActivity.java).

---Update---

It seems there is something wrong with other settings. Now it keeps processing the image. And my emulator doesn't get the image set.

Comment: Please upload sorter image. so that folks can see in at-least desktop screen properly.

Comment: Try a different camera app. There are plenty in the store.

Comment: @blackapps I want to use the system default one :)

Comment: Ok. But to test your code use other apps yoo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem of mine is I forgot to check the permission of writing memory as saving the picture taken requires it:

```
if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED) {
    requestPermissions(new String[]{ Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE }, WRITE_STORAGE);
```

Adding this properly would make my camera work.

My source code is [here](https://github.com/SeakyLuo/RandomMenu/blob/master/app/src/main/java/personalprojects/seakyluo/randommenu/EditFoodActivity.java).

Answer (score 0):

**You are using "OnePlus 7 Pro" to run your app** 
and it's OS is Android 9.0 (Pie).

If you target to run your application that OS is upper then N you need some file sharing setting

1.Specify the FileProvider

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.myapp">
<application
    ...>
    <provider
        android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="com.example.myapp.fileprovider"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true"
        android:exported="false">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/filepaths" />
    </provider>
    ...
  </application>
</manifest>
```

2.Specify sharable directories in res/xml/filepaths.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <external-path name="my_images" path="Android/data/com.example.package.name/files/Pictures" />
</paths>
```

3. Change some code in on onActivityResult

   ```
   //*******
    Bitmap image = null;
    switch (requestCode){
    case CAMERA_CODE:
    Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
    image = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");
    break;
   //*****
   ```

[Android Developer Code Link for file sharing provider setting](https://developer.android.com/training/secure-file-sharing/setup-sharing)

[Android Developer Code Link how to Take Photos](https://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics)